# Libraries to navigate and choose path based on congestion level?

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, routing, navigation

I'm trying to develop a system to get best path to travel user based on road traffic (congestion level). Functionality of the system should be provide least congested path for traveler given destination from his/her current location.

Note - I'm using OSGeo live 6.5 , Postgresql , MapServer wms services etc. for now.

There are routing libraries like pgroute to get shortest path. Is there such libraries/tool that we can use for above stated development?

Answer (score 1):

You still want the shortest path but based on travel time instead of travel distance. There is no need to look for different tools. You only need to set travel times for road network links and modify them based on congestion level to take longer during congested periods.

Comment: if you use pgrouting , just replace use congestion level as cost value. Read more about dijktra and graph theory. Also remenber that default postgresql serialization only can access data wich has been committed into db when you start your query